# Send grepped tail output to netcat

Tags: unix, grep, tail, netcat

I am trying to run the following command, and nothing is getting sent to netcat

```
tail -F file.txt | grep test | nc host 9999
```

If I remove the grep, the tail successfully is followed and sent to netcat.

If I just run the following, data comes back, so I know that data should be getting sent to the nc pipe:

```
tail -F file.txt | grep test
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I added the following to unbuffer the piped output and nothing goes through:

```
tail -F file.txt | stdbuf -o0 grep test | nc host 9999
```

When I turn on line buffering, output is cut off

```
tail -F file.txt | grep --line-buffered test | nc host 9999
```

Where

```
workid: ID:ITEST_HGR1-EMS12103.1A156BB6CEB1:10F76E5D
```

is sent as

```
workid: ID:ITEST_HGR1-EMS12103.1A156BB6CEB1:10F7
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the default buffering behavior of `grep`. If you're on a GNU grep, you can use `grep --line-buffered`, or try `unbuffer`.

Comment: this got me closer, except it appears lines are getting cut off. For example, the nc listener now prints:  workid: ID:ITEST_HGR1-EMS12103.1A156BB6CEB1:10F7     whereas the actual grepped output should be workid: ID:ITEST_HGR1-EMS12103.1A156BB6CEB1:10F76E5D

Comment: I tried adding stdbuf -o0 before the grep statement and nothing goes through

Comment: If you remove netcat are the lines cut off, or not?

Comment: also appears that both stdbuf and unbuffer are not installed on this VM (I do not have ability to install it as it is managed by another group)

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried piping through xargs calling netcat?